# javascript evaluation failed- karate

Tags: call, karate, web-api-testing

I am trying to call an API in second feature file , passing arguments from first feature file . These has to be passed as a param for second API

```
* def activeDetails =
    """
      function(times){
        for(i=0;i<=times;i++){
          karate.log('Run test round: '+(i+1));
          karate.call('getActiveRouteDetails.feature', { token: token, currentPage: i });
        }
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(1*1000);
      }
    """
* call activeDetails totalPages
```

In my second feature , I am able to print the values passed , Getting error while passing it as a param 'no step-definition method match found for: param pageNumber'

```
And print currentPage
And print token
And param pageNumber = '#currentPage'
And param token = token
```

Answer (score 0):

Watch the white space around the `=` sign. Normally if you use IDE support you can avoid these issues. You seem to have an extra space after `pageNumber`.

So make this change:

```
And param pageNumber = currentPage
```

I request you to please read the docs and examples. You are still un-necessarily making 2 calls. And over complicating your test.

Comment: Hi Sir , I am getting the following error still. examples.getActiveRouteDetails: getActiveRouteDetails.feature:18 - javascript evaluation failed: currentPage, ReferenceError: "currentPage" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1

Comment: @anonymous time for me to ask you to follow this process, or you can wait for someone else to try help you: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue